# Android Ad requests using AdMob

Tags: android, admob

I am using AdMob to serve Ad's on my application.

Are Android Ad requests served without network connection i.e. Let's say AdMob is serving a request when there is network connection and typically it takes 30 seconds for a request to be completed.

After say 45 seconds my network connection goes off, will my Ad request be served as long as the Ad is visible on the activity or the request will be incomplete and resume or start afresh after network connectivity is restored ?

Thanks,
Adithya

Answer (score 0):

Every request should be refreshed after 60 seconds as for the Admob Policy .

if your app doesn't have the network connection means you can't hit the Admob Api.

after every 30/60 seconds ad's will be refreshed automatically , so you no need to worry about it.

if network is available, a new request will hit the Admob ,  if the user changes his orientation within 30/60 seconds then again a new request will hit the Admob.

Hope you got you what you need.  All the Best